# open specific file in appropriate app from inside Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm creating Windows 8 app in which i need to list specific files in a page and then let user open that file. I'm using C# as backend.

I want to ask this (as in the image below), to my user when they try to open any app listed in my app page.

when user select specific app, then the file that is clicked should open in that app.

[image: when user select specific app, then the file that is clicked should open in that app.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike previous versions of Windows, the User is now [in control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of file associations.

To show the launch using the Window above, you can refer to the complete example of launching options [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec/sourcecode?fileId=43565&pathId=918152775).

The core of it is deciding on a `Point` on the screen (which is `openWithPosition` in the example below) and then calling `LaunchUriAsync` with the options set to display the window.

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions(); 
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true; 
options.UI.InvocationPoint = openWithPosition; 
options.UI.PreferredPlacement = Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Below; 

// Launch the URI. 
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

The linked example code contains a function that can compute a reasonable `Point` given a XAML element.

Comment: ohh, I don't know how I missed this sample.
Thanx anyways..!!